# PFObject values may not have class: _SwiftValue

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3, parse-server, xcode8

We are trying out `Parse server`, and we have never used Parse SDK before.
As part of learning we tried `Facebook login with Parse`, that worked good. Next we wanted to save the retrieved user information and we are stuck at saving the `Profile picture`.

**The Code**

```
let pictureURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookID)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"
let imageData = NSData.init(contentsOf: NSURL(string: pictureURL) as! URL)
let picture = PFFile(data: imageData! as Data)
PFUser.current()?.setObject(picture, forKey: "profilePicture")
PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground()
```

And it crashes on the line `setObject` with the following log:

[image: crash log - image]

Any help is much appreciated to get this issue resolved. Thanks!

Comment: try `NSData` instead of `Data`. Here: `let picture = PFFile(data: imageData! as Data)`

Comment: @Mr.UB It is `public convenience init?(data: Data)`, thus not accepting `NSData`. However I tried this `let picture = PFFile(data: (imageData! as NSData) as Data)` and got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens when you pass Optional something to `Any`.

Try this:

```
    if let picture = PFFile(data: imageData! as Data) {
        PFUser.current()?.setObject(picture, forKey: "profilePicture")
        PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground()
    }
```

Or simply this, if you are sure that `picture` can never be nil:

```
    let picture = PFFile(data: imageData! as Data)
    PFUser.current()?.setObject(picture!, forKey: "profilePicture")
    PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground()
```