# Error when setting whereKey in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have below code.Which results **crash** my iOS app. I have a table that has two pointer columns pointing to User class.

Crash `error` message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query
>   for type: _SwiftValue'

Strange thing is same four lines work in another Swift file !!

these are first four lines within `if` statement so no other code is executed before these.

```
let currentUser = PFUser.current()    
let query = PFQuery(className: "friend_list")

query.whereKey("friend_of", equalTo: currentUser)
query.whereKey("friend_with", equalTo: anotherUser)
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks Ashish

Comment: Do you need to unwrap the value of `PFUser.current()` ?

Comment: No xcode asks to delete "?"

Comment: Then set a breakpoint and examine your variables. Step through and see where the problem is.

Comment: I did that many times. currentUser has valid value. if i comment out fist whereKey then crashes on second. I tried to delete Parse class from data browser and even changed column names.

Comment: Step into the parse code, see where the exception is thrown

Comment: Below is stack trace. it fails at PFQueryAssertValidEqualityClauseClass  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011063734b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011009821e objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001106a0265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
 3   Parse                               0x000000010d699e3a PFQueryAssertValidEqualityClauseClass + 746
 4   Parse                               0x000000010d699acc -[PFQuery whereKey:equalTo:] + 92
 5

Comment: Right, and what class does the debugger show that the value was. It thinks that it is `_swiftValue` not PFObject or some such

Comment: yes it is `_swiftValue`

Comment: Most likely you have used an optional or `Any` somewhere else. Be particularly careful,if you have used foundation classes such as `NSArray` as these will return `AnyObjext` by default http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509300/pfobject-values-may-not-have-class-swiftvalue

Comment: You this worked **(PFUser.current())!**. After a good amount of coding optional is still giving me trouble !! Thanks for pointers. Appreciate